# Python - Keyword arguments using variable as key - fun(self.key="value)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to achieve the following:

```
calculate_fun(self.key1="some_value", self.key2="another_value")
```

Basically use a variable as the key for a Keyword variable.

Currently, if I try this it errors out as it is not accepting a variable on the left hand side of the "=" sign. It is expecting something in the form of:

```
calculate_fun(field1="some_value", field2="another_value")
```

But that means that I need to hardcode field1 and field2. I would like the keyword to be a variable so I can change it at runtime, hence field1 can become field55 at runtime.

Comment: Are you serious? The person who answered my question had it exactly right.

Comment: He only made a wild guess and got it right. But to me what you wrote seems like you wanted to have to automatically perform and assignment to an instance attribute when calling a function, which doesn't make any sense. I downvoted your question because, as it currently stands, it cannot be understood by future readers. I'll lift it when you make the question clearer.

Comment: @Bakuriu no wild guess, although poorly worded (before the edit), this question _does_ make sense.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Exactly, in this case it's also a (obvious) duplicate.

Comment: Clearly a duplicate, but it should be noted that the `def f(**kwargs)` stated in the accepted answer of the original is not necessary.

Comment: Yes. It is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with dictionary unpacking:

```
calculate_fun(**{self.key1: "some_value", self.key2: "another_value"})
```